# Using boost from xcode 4.4 - unable to access the regex library

Tags: xcode, boost

I am fairly new to c++ and I need to use regular expressions and more libraries of that type that do not come with Xcode. I have found boost but i dont know how to install it. I thought it worked but it did not recognize the regex library for boost. I typed it in correctly.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use libc++, which comes with Xcode 4.4, then you can use the C++11 `<regex>` library. Just go to the project's build settings and set the C++ standard library to be libc++. Turn on C++11 while you're at it.

Comment: It comes with C++11, which added a number of libraries first introduced in boost. C++11 has smart pointers, more containers and algorithms, a better time library, and much more.